# Pointer sizes in different compilers

Tags: c++, types, sizeof

Let's say we're targetting one particular hardware architecture, one particular operating system (if applicable) and one particular "bitness" (32 vs. 64 etc). In such case, is it safe to assume that different compilers will use the same `sizeof(T*)` for the same `T`? Does the standard rule on this one way or another?

Even if it's not guaranteed by the standard, would/does this hold for "most normal compilers intended for normal use and efficiency?" I can imagine a theoretical Hell++ would use different sizes if allowed, but how about compilers people actually use?

I would also be interested in other types I see as closely related to pointers (`std::size_t` , `std::ptrdiff_t`, `std::intptr_t`).

As a "bonus question," can anything be said about other built-in types (e.g. `char`, `int`, `float`, `long`)? However, encountering different sizes across compilers wouldn't really surprise me with these.

**EDIT**

One more piece to consider: would this be affected by `extern "C"` linkage? As an example of application, if I have a library which publishes this function:

```
extern "C" void foo(void *);
```

is it theoretically possible I will not be able to call the function correctly, because the library's compiler used a different `sizeof(void*)` than my compiler does?

Comment: "bitness" ==> "processor word length"

Comment: On some architectures char* needs more space than int*. void* must be good for any T*, but T* may be smaller taking alignment into consideration

Comment: Why would this matter?

Answer (score 4):

No, pointers to different data types are not required to be of the same size. One particular case when a pointer may not have an "expected" size is pointers to member functions. In order to be able to support virtual functions, member function pointers are usually implemented using some sort of struct, an array of pointers, whatever. For example, on my architecture, `void *` is 8 bytes long, but `(Foo::*)()` is 16:

```
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ cat quirk.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Foo {
    public:
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "bar()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof void *: " << sizeof(void *) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof (Foo::*)(): " << sizeof(&Foo::bar) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ clang++ -Wall -o quirk quirk.cpp
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ ./quirk
sizeof void *: 8
sizeof (Foo::*)(): 16
```

The size of other types (`int`, `float`, etc.) will also vary widely depending on compiler, architecture, and even some compiler flags and settings.

Comment: Thanks. However, I was actually more interested in pointers to the *same* type on different *compilers.*

Comment: @Angew Expect those to be of different sizes too. In particular, never rely on a type being of a particular size. (The only exceptions are fixed- and minimal size integers, such as `std::uint32_t`).

Comment: I always teach to NOT treat pointer-to-member as pointer, and that we get kinda regular pointer when combined with instance

Comment: @BalogPal Well, pointers are pointers... this is especially why the Standard doesn't enforce regulations nor does it make assumptions about their size.

Comment: my point is having word pointer in PTM is mostly misleading and common source of confusion. sure, the standard put it there so we have to bite the bullet

Comment: @BalogPal: actually, that's pretty much what the standard says: (3.9.2/3) "Except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members."